# java.lang.NullPointerException encountered in an unexpected place

Tags: java, android

I'm perplexed about this question:
Is there a situation in which the first line in the following three lines can produce java.lang.NullPointerException?

```
if (mJobs == null || mJobs.size() == 0) { <-- trace shows exception here
    return null;
}
```

This exception is seen on an unrooted Android 4.4.4 phone. 
mJobs is declared like this:

```
ArrayList<Job> mJobs;
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Update: This crash happened one time out many thousands of runs.

Comment: Can we see the stack trace? Is `Job` a class you wrote?

Comment: Clean, rebuild, test again. And make sure the exception is no thrown from inside the Job.size() method.

Comment: You should really post a stack trace and even the Job class.  You probably want to make it clearer by using mJobs.isEmpty() anyway.

Comment: Guys, there's no additional info in the trace.

Comment: bphilipnyc, good point about .isEmpty().

Comment: Actually, size() is just a counter - shouldn't have to care about Job.  All it will do is return the number of elements as @Troy mentions.  Are you sure that the NPE occurs at that line and not at a method that is calling this code?

Comment: I just noticed you updated the question. This is happened once? If it's not consistent, then this may be a threading issue or a resource issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, assuming you are using `java.util.ArrayList` and not your own implementation.

It would be clearer to use `isEmpty()` instead of `size() == 0`.  I would also check to see how this code is getting called since you are returning `null` in either of those two cases.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that there is any way that your `NullPointerException` is coming from that first line of code.  I bet you are running code that was compiled from a different version of the source code that you are looking at leaving you to believe that the error is on a different line than it really is.  I would recompile your current code and then run it fresh.

Comment: or the exception was thrown from inside the Job.size() method.

Comment: He is not calling the Job.size() method.  He is calling the size method on the arraylist.  mJobs is an arraylist.  Since he already checked if the arraylist was not null through his short circuiting ||, then he can safely check its size.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to say that the java "short-circuit" evaluation should never cause mJobs.size() to be evaluated, you might try it anyway to see if this is where it fails.

```
if (mJobs == null) {
    return null;
}
if (mJobs.size() == 0) { <-- trace shows exception here
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please explain, do you have any source on this? I always thought mJobs.size() will never be evaluated in the case the left part of the OR was true.

Comment: There's no reason to separate due to short circuiting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this explanation is not valid. At least I really want it to be invalid. :)

Answer (score 0):

If mJobs is null then there is the possibility to throw the null pointer exception in mjobs.size()

```
if (mJobs == null || (mJobs !=null && mJobs.size() == 0)) { 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not really, no. `||` short-circuits. *In* `size`, possibly, but the non-null check is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, but you answer is so wrong. In the case mJobs == null evaluates to true then mJobs !=null evaluates to false and if it is not shortcuted in the left part it is not shortcuted in the right part also.

Comment: If mJobs != null evaluates to false it wont execute the right part

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the or of course, or means what it says, so the run time is evaluating both sides of the or for true before moving on. Short circuit does not occur in an or evaluation, so you can combine them in a single evaluation with short circuit if you use a ternary operation. Works the same as splitting them out, just shorter.

```
if (mJobs == null ? true : mJobs.size() == 0) { 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not true according to the spec.  If mJobs is null, the right side is not evaluated, at least in Java.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24